# class constructor is not hit after the service onStart() in windows service using C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

In following code snippet is a windows service that I am trying to test but I came across with a problem that the class constructor is not get called after the execution of onStart() method. I tried to debug the service and I would like to seek advice from experts.

```
public partial class ServiceTest : ServiceBase
{
    public ServiceTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("ServiceTest Source"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
            "ServiceTest Source", "ServiceTest Log");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "ServiceTest Source";
        eventLog1.Log = "ServiceTest Log";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("ServiceTest service started on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());


        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

        string ProcessHour = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProcessHour"];
        int intProcessHour = Convert.ToInt32(ProcessHour);

        DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;

        if (dtNow.Hour < intProcessHour)
        {
            DateTime dtToday = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime dtStartDateTime = dtToday.AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(ProcessHour));
            System.TimeSpan diff = dtStartDateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
            timer1.Interval = diff.TotalMilliseconds;
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime dtToday = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime dtStartDateTime = dtToday.AddDays(1).AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(ProcessHour));
            System.TimeSpan diff = dtStartDateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
            timer1.Interval = diff.TotalMilliseconds;
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("ServiceTest service stopped on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            timer1.Stop();

            string StartTimer, EndTimer;
            StartTimer = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("ServiceTest timer1_Elapsed begin on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            /*Some Logic*/
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that the constructor is not called **after** `onStart()` is normal. However if `onStart()` is ever called then obviously constructor was called as well previously. You cannot execute instance method before you've created an instance.

Comment: yes true, but while debugging it don't hit the other methods such as timer_Elapsed()

Comment: No problem here as well as you never call `timer_Elapsed()`.

Comment: should I call it in onStart(), is it legal?

Comment: Actually I can't see any code where you define your `timer1`.

Comment: the last method is timer1_Elapsed(object sender,system.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)

Comment: In the future, please format your code so it is readable.

Answer (score 1):

Service constructor will be called *before* OnStart() method, not after.

OnStart() is just like any other c# method, and, unless static, will be called on a class instance, so after the constructor.

Comment: sounds good. but while debugging the code it just hit onStart() not even timer_Elapsed()

Comment: Well, looks like you are not calling timer_elapsed() anywhere. Did you forget to post a piece of code? Maybe the Timer() definition?